# Can i use multiple and condition or where in grouping in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-8

Here is my table structure and data as

[image]

I need a data to filter like, get list of doctor, user combination (group by) where match both condition like ANSWER is "Male" and "Below 30".

i have tried below query but not working perfecly.

1. `select * from doctor_classification_question_answers where (question_id = 11 and answer like '["Female"]') and (question_id = 12 and answer like '["Below 30"]') group by user_id, doctor_id;`
2. `select * from doctor_classification_question_answers where (question_id,answer) in ((11,'["Male"]'),(12,'Below 30')) group by user_id, doctor_id`

there is many other type of answer which combination of question. if anyone can help.

I want a unique user_id and doctor_id combination who fulfill given condition.

Comment: I think you should use OR?
`WHERE question_id = 11 AND answer LIKE '["Female"]' OR question_id 12 AND answer '["Below 30"]'`. Otherwise you will keep getting multiple rows returned.

Comment: If you want user_id, doctor_id for q=11,A=Female OR q=12, A=Below 30, then a simple OR condition will work, as outlined by @geerjanknapen

Comment: However, if you want user_id, doctor_id for q=11,A=Female AND q=12, A=Below 30, (for the same user_id, doctor_id) that is a little more complex.  You could either do it with a union and HAVING clause, or a self-join

Comment: i want it with AND condition .

Comment: @RobEyre any ref plz if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, depending on your table setup.  This is the self-join version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.user_id, a1.doctor_id
FROM doctor_classification_answers a1
INNER JOIN doctor_classification_answers a2 ON a1.user_id = a2.user_id AND a1.doctor_id = a2.doctor_id
WHERE a1.question_id = 11 AND a1.answer_id = '["Female"]'
AND a2.question_id = 12 AND a2.answer_id = '["Below 30"]'
```

or if you want to use a GROUP BY/HAVING clause, this might suit

```
SELECT user_id, doctor_id
FROM doctor_classification_answers
WHERE question_id = 11 AND answer_id = '["Female"]'
OR question_id = 12 AND answer_id = '["Below 30"]'
GROUP BY user_id, doctor_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

(presuming you have a unique key on user_id, doctor_id and question_id)

Which you choose will depend on your table structure and data.  I would recommend testing each for accuracy and performance